# Background image doesn't display in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display the background image of the website which is set by admin and comes from slider table in a database but the image doesn't display when I call it in CSS code.

But **if I call it in `<img src="">` tag it works**.

### PHP code

```
@php
$sliders = App\Models\Slider::find(1);
@endphp
```

### CSS blade code

```
.page-header {
    background-image: url ({{ asset($sliders->slider_img) }});
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Is the css code in a .blade.php file?

Comment: yes this style in same html blade.php file

Comment: in that case, can you share the output in the style tag? The problem could be the missing quotes around the image URL, but i'm not sure.

Comment: $sliders->slider_img  it has a value but in css here show me empty image 
may the  way that i call the image it is uncorrect in css

Comment: what dus `@dd(asset($sliders->slider_img))` output

Comment: i got path of the image correctly  by @dd(asset($sliders->slider_img))

Comment: the result is  upload/slider/1711415057606880.PNG

Comment: So it's missing a `/` at the start

Comment: i tried doesn't work

Comment: does it work if you open the image url in the browser?

Comment: yes it is opening

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
.page-header {
    background-image: url ('/{{ asset($sliders->slider_img) }}');
    position: relative;
}
```

you forgot the quotes ' ' before and after the image path.

Comment: still not working

Comment: try to do this in blade view, use css inline in a tag with background-image and check it works.

Comment: @ALAAELDIN combine add the leading `/` and the quotes.